# berkeley db debian wheezy

Tags: bitcoind, linux

I am trying to make a website that supports bitcoin, but I cant install bitcoin core because berkeleydb is under 4.8. I tried installing it via apt-get squeeze repository but that didn't work. I also downloaded the tar.gz file and installed that but that also didn't work. Does anyone know how I can install berkeleydb or what linux distro has full support of berkeleydb?

Answer (score 1):

Here is good guide (read comments too)
https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-compile-and-install-bitcoin-core-on-debian-wheezy/

also you can use bdb 5.1 (./configure --with-incompatible-bdb) if you don't have a plan to move bitcoin data to/from other computer

Comment: I strongly suggest that you not use an incompatible bdb. The time it costs you later is *not worth* the time you save.

Comment: @NickODell, isn't incompatible bdb just for compatibility with older wallets? Why would you need compatibility with older wallets if you're starting a new wallet from scratch?

Comment: @StephenM347 I was under the impression that later versions like 5.1 weren't compatible with bdb 4.8, meaning that the wallet you created using bdb 5.1 instructions wouldn't be compatible with a bitcoin core client built using bdb 4.8. That's probably worth a question of its own, though. http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/42965/do-berkley-db-versions-need-to-be-the-same

Comment: @Nick Yes, a wallet.dat touched by bdb 5.1 won't be readable by a bdb 4.8 version. However, it's trivial to convert it back if needed (db5.1_dump wallet51.dat | db4.8_load wallet48.dat)